# testcafe ERROR Unable to open the "chrome:headless" browser

Tags: java, maven, testcafe, aws-codepipeline, google-chrome-headless

I have a maven project running end-to-end tests on the integration-test phase with testcafe

I'm getting `ERROR Unable to open the "chrome:headless" browser` on the aws codepipeline for 2 days, before that, without any change on the pipeline it was running successfully.

command for testcafe: `testcafe chrome:headless`

To run npm commands in the maven project I use the `com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.15.0` plugin and this was part of the integration-test phase on my pipeline.

```
[INFO] > shop-e2e@1.0.0 test-shop-chrome
[INFO] > testcafe chrome:headless
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using CONFIG: {"baseUrl":"http://localhost:18888"}
[INFO] ERROR Unable to open the "chrome:headless" browser due to the following error:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Error: No inspectable targets
[INFO]     at defaultTarget (/codebuild/output/src123/src/git-codecommit.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/shop/src/test/e2e/node_modules/chrome-remote-interface/lib/chrome.js:48:23)
[INFO]     at Chrome._fetchDebuggerURL (/codebuild/output/src123/src/git-codecommit.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/shop/src/test/e2e/node_modules/chrome-remote-interface/lib/chrome.js:193:28)
[INFO]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[INFO]     at Chrome._start (/codebuild/output/src123/src/git-codecommit.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/shop/src/test/e2e/node_modules/chrome-remote-interface/lib/chrome.js:140:25)
[INFO] 
[INFO] Type "testcafe -h" for help.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:10 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-23T10:29:34Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.15.0:npm (e2e-npm-test) on project shop: Failed to run task: 'npm run test-shop-chrome' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.15.0:npm (e2e-npm-test) on project shop: Failed to run task
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
```

First, I thought there was a problem with installing Chrome but it installed successfully.

Afterwards, I updated the frontend-maven-plugin version and there was no change as well.

I'm not sure what could've been changed, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please confirm that the issue is similar to the one from [this github ticket](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/8145) on github? If so, then please share a working example in the ticket and monitor its status.

Comment: following the github ticket, thank you Pavel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Pavel Morozov stated in his comment, testcafe is aware of the problem and they are working on the fix.

As a workaround from the [github issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/8145) I had to use the new headless mode of Chrome(it's also required for Chromium)

```
testcafe 'chrome --headless=new'
```

quotes are needed

Answer (score 1):

You should provide your code. so I can give you the way how to open chrome in headless mode. You can cross-verify with how you do it

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

Please Give me feedback as it is my first time answering

Comment: it's testcafe that opens the chrome:headless with the `testcafe chrome:headless` command. I'm not using Selenium to open Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well when running testcafe on chromium:headless in debian. I noticed it went from version 121.0.6167.160 when it was last successful to 122.0.6261.57 today.

When I install the older version, I don't run into the issue. Not a solution, but a workaround for now.

Comment: this comment is actually helpful but I couldn't find a way to install an old version of Chrome on my pipeline.
this is how I install chrome normally
`wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -`
`echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list`
`apt-get update && apt-get install -y -qq google-chrome-stable`